# Analysis Service Processing Task doesn't save the processing options changes

Tags: ssis, ssas, visual-studio-2022, tabular

I use Visual Studio 2022 and SSIS to develop an Analysis Services Processing task to process Tabular Cube. I'm trying to change the processing options and remove the check on Process affected objects, when save changes and open processing options again I didn't find my changes applied it return back again to the default settings. Is there a bug in Visual Studio, How to fix this issue, save and apply my changes?

[image]

Comment: It's possible that there might be an issue with the project file (.dtproj) that is preventing the changes from being saved correctly. Make sure there are no syntax errors or conflicting settings in the project file. Create a new package and test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked in new project. The same issue exists.